# How can I update XML files in Powershell containing ascii characters greater than 126?

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm reading in an xml file, updating a value and writing it back - all fairly easy excpet for the fact that the file I'm updating contains a right curly single quote `’` character.  The first time I save the file this gets replaced with `â€™`.  The more times I run it the worse it gets and the file size starts to grow exponentially.

I have worked out this happens to any character with an ascii value over 126 and that I can prevent this by replacing the `’` characer with `&#8217;` however, there must be a better way!

Any advice on how to save XML files correctly - my only thought is to search through the entire xml file for any chacter with ascii value > 126 and replace it.

My current code is:

```
$Path = "C:\path\to\file.xml"
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $Path 
$xml.Save($Path)
```

Comment: You can pass an encoding to `Get-Content`. What happens if you pass the encoding of `file.xml`

Comment: Ahh, so simple!  Worked perfectly thanks.

Comment: Note that technically, there's only one ASCII character >126. Everything above 127 is non-ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your file is encoded in a way that allows `Get-Content` to auto-detect the encoding (like UTF-8 or UTF-16 with the proper [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) you need to tell the cmdlet which encoding to use:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.xml' -Encoding UTF8
```

or create an `Xml` object and use its `Load()` method, which will use the encoding specified in the XML preamble and throw an error if it encounters characters that don't match that encoding:

```
$xml = New-Object Xml
$xml.Load('C:\path\to\your.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somehing like this

```
$Path = "C:\path\to\file.xml"
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $Path -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify encoding for `Get-Content` Cmdlet.

```
Get-Content $Path -Encoding ENCODING_HERE
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment as I started writing my answer, tried out my code in PowerShell and then posted it.

Comment: ah, fair enough :)